# Modern web app MVC Core 2 : Pure JavaScript or Angural?

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-core-2.0

Starting from scratch in the development of a modern web app would you recommend developing using only JavaScript instead of Angular?

For some time I have been developing some small project to learn how to use Angular but I find it a bit verbose even if in the last versions has been improved a lot, you have to do many steps for a simple thing ..

Working with MVC core 2 and Javascript (possibly with the supported TypeScript) is simpler in the initial development of a project, in practice you use javascript only in the pages where you need so without having to do everything necessary with angular even the easiest thing.

What do you think about it ? How would you develop a project from scratch?

Comment: ⚠ You are entering *The Opinion Zone*! ⚠

Comment: (Seriously, this is a terribly broad, opinionated, product recommendation question that is massively off-topic. I hold strong opinions on what technologies **I** would use, and the amount of detail here would leave me firmly in the "Well, it depends" camp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply wrap my Knockout Variables in a closure allowing them to be accessed by the DOM
anywhere anytime within the application. I store my data in 1 single JSON object that may
have properties that are populated from several Ajax calls.

That's it. I too don't see the need for things like 2 way bindings, controllers/components, service injection, JavaScript testing ??